# Django RSS feed 500 error

Tags: python, django, rss, django-rss

I'm working on setting up an RSS feed for my Django-based blog.  I'm getting 500 errors when I try and access the URL:

```
$ curl -I http://172.16.91.140:8000/blogg/feeds/latest/
HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

WSGIServer is reporting nothing more than

```
[25/Aug/2011 20:21:41] "HEAD /blogg/feeds/latest/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0
```

Under blogg/ I've got two files:

feeds.py:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed
from blog.models import *

class BlogFeed(Feed):
    title = "Test Title"
    link = "/sitenews/"
    description = "Test Description"

    def items(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter( is_published = True ).order_by('-id')[:10]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.subject

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.subject

    def item_pubdate(self,item):
        return item.blog_time
```

and urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from blog.feeds import *

feeds = {
    'latest': feeds.BlogFeed,
}

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^past-bloggs/', 'country_listing'),
    (r'^past-bloggs/(?P<country_name>\w+)/$', 'city_listing'),
    )

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', {'feed_dict': feeds}, name='feeds'),
)
```

Any idea where I could be going wrong?  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Calling

```
return item.subject
```

Meant there was an invalid property, I changed it to

```
return item.blog_subject
```

School boy error.  Sorry I hadn't included my model as well.  Sometimes writing out a problem will cause me to notice something I've overlooked.  Happy coding everyone!